# Angular.js state of objects not being saved to global scope

Tags: angularjs, object, scope

I have a JS object that I'm using to save the current state of some data on my site, to be utilized in another function later.  The data is saved within a function, and then later accessed from another function.

```
$scope.object = {"name": " ", "age": " ", "phone" : " " }

$scope.setData = function() {

        $scope.object.name = "Alex";
        $scope.object.age = "23";
        $scope.object.phone = "123-456-4321"

        //Data will output here just fine
        console.log($scope.object.name)
        console.log($scope.object.age)
        console.log($scope.object.phone)
    }

    $scope.getData = function() {
        //No data will print here after I have set the object.  Why is this?
        console.log($scope.object.name)
        console.log($scope.object.age)
        console.log($scope.object.phone)

    }

$scope.setData();
$scope.getData();
```

The problem is, when I try to access the object's data from another function, it cannot read the data that I saved in the original function.  I'm thinking this may have something to do with me not accessing the current scope correctly, but I am not 100% sure.  I am used to vanilla JS where  I would be able to access this object since it is within global scope.  All help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "access the object's data from another function"? In the code sample you are calling `getData()` immediately after `setData()` - is this not the case in the real world?

Also, where are the `setData` & `getData` functions implemented? In a Controller? In the same Controller?

Comment: @MS_AU yes they are both implemented in same controller.  It's the fact that when I run the getData() function the console.log prints nothing, as if the object's properties are empty, although they should not be because I set the objects properties in the setData() function.

Comment: Can you please post the full code. Also, if you are using this method somewhere else, please post that too. Also, please try if you can create a fiddle for this issue.

Comment: I'm guessing you may have multiple instances on the same Controller? Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4t3wpys/1/ which seems to work fine. If you like, update it to reflect how your app behaves.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to print the data in bouth functions? Because, if thats the case, works fine to me.  The only thing that I did was to take the `""` from the json parameters. 
[image: Copy exactly as you have]

Then, in my console I have

[image: Console log]